# 5 extra qts of oil in Hustler Z super diesel motor with a Warren cat engine

Tags: oil, diesel, service, dipstick

So while i was servicing our mower today. I spaced on remembering it was 1.5 qts of diesel engine oil. I put in 2. I'm new to servicing my own equipment because the price to service is more than my account can manage rn. on the dipstick its maybe an inch or 1.5 inches past the max fill line.

so right now im either thinking to open the drain plug and drain some out tomorrow or to leave it in there, test out the mower and look at the dipstick to see if any foam or bubbles will be present. after that im lost on what I should do if i do have proplems. Thank you for any help.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Why not just drain it all out into a clean container and put the correct amount back in.

Comment: that is a solid idea

Comment: The title say "5 extra qts of oil" but the question text says you added 2 qts. Further, the question text is also unclear if you drained the engine oil before adding more, or if you did not drain the old oil. Please clarify.

Answer (score 1):

First of all DO NOT under any circumstances start or run the engine with that amount of excess oil in the crankcase.  You can cause severe damage almost immediately. Oil can be forced past the piston rings and into the combustion chambers, oil can be churned into a froth and then be unable to be pumped by the oil pump, starving the engine of lubrication, or any of a host of other things can happen.

One way or the other you need to get the excess oil out and get the oil in the crankcase to the proper level.  Two ways come to my mind:

1. You can siphon (or pump) out out of the dipstick tube using a small (and clean) hose.
2. You can drain the oil out using the usual oil drain plug.

In either case you should then check the oil level and add any to bring the level back up into the normal range.